# Change default from "Attachment post URL" to "File URL" in Add Media

Tags: uploads, urls, media

When a user upload images, by default, the Attachment Post URL option is selected. How can I change the default to be "File URL"? If that is not possible, how can I remove the attachment post url completely?

I made a Google search that brought more [questionmarks](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-attachment-post-url-button-from-media-upload?replies=3) than answers.

EDIT:

I found a way to disable the attachment post URL, this code works:

```
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'my_attachment_fields_edit', 10, 2); 
function my_attachment_fields_edit($form_fields,$post){ 
    //Set attachment link to none and hide it.
    $html = "<input type='hidden' name='attachments[".$post->ID."][url]' value=''/>";

    $form_fields['url']['html'] = $html; //Replace html
    $form_fields['url']['label'] = ''; //Remove label
    $form_fields['url']['helps'] ='';//Remove help text

    return $form_fields;
}
```

However I am still looking for a way to change which one is set as default.

Comment: From some [Answers here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Attachment+Post+URL%22) and looking at the core (`wp-admin/includes/media.php`), seems that's not possible. The linked search query only return 7 results, take a look to see if you can extract something from those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre almost there.  The func I show in [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40532/change-attachment-post-urls-to-file-urls/70337#70337%20%20this%20thread) sets the 'large' as default, but also, in that thread, you'll see

> There is a hidden options page in WordPress under yoursite.com/wp-admin/options.php On that endless list of undocumented options you can set a value for "image_default_link_type". You may want to set it to "file" (without the quotes)